# MYSQL cтранности

Tags: php, mysql

Привет! Такое дело. При обработке форичем массива приходится обрабатывать поле через `utf8_decode()`, а потом хочу проверить, есть ли оно в базе данных.

Так вот. Строка вида `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'table' WHERE 'name' = '".utf8_decode($name)."'"` не возвращает ничего, при чем `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'table' WHERE 'name' = 'somename'"` возвращает правильно, и `echo utf8_decode($name)` возвращает `somename`.

В чем может быть проблема, ребят?) Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы

Comment: Sql injection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

разобрался, нужно использовать `trim()` =)

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим Вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку "Опубликовать ответ" следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.

Comment: @metalurgus, вообще-то это ответ.